# "Limit Exceeded: Email body size" when putting a URL in the body

Tags: google-apps-script

Whenever I include the URL in the body, I get **Limit Exceeded: Email Body Size.**

Is there anyway to get around this?

```
function CustomEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zajVyOx6y_26yjDmEOFtAZVHc_Mr5UNg1EP8YBjGj0s"); 

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Follow Up List");

var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C4");

var UserData = range.getValues();

for (i in UserData) {

var row = UserData[i];

var name = row[0];
var email = row[1];
var cell = row[2];

var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zajVyOx6y_26yjDmEOFtAZVHc_Mr5UNg1EP8YBjGj0s/edit?usp=sharing');

var emailbody =     url

MailApp.sendEmail(row[1],
                "Continual Improvement Reminder for cell - "+ cell,
                mybody,{htmlbody:emailbody});

}
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are using the entire contents returned by the URL not just emailing a URL. How big is the content returned from the UrlFetchApp.fetch()?

Comment: You can see if you're hitting the limits based on the [App Script Quota Limits](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard).

Comment: Hitting the same limit here, and the message is literally a condensed down version of a message that's already in the inbox. :|